# Responsive class is not working in laravel 5.3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, npm, vue.js

I am using laravel and vuejs

Laravel is using this line to import bootstrap css

```
// Bootstrap
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

In `app.scss` file

After `npm install` all bootstrap class is working except responsive class.

I am using below classes

```
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/
```

Example : To display only in desktop, I am using class `hidden-md-down`.

but when I use below css cdn responsive classes works and other classes breaks.

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

If you have faced and fixed this kind of issue please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Are v3 and v4 of bootstrap supposed to be compatible?

Comment: How can I check version ? I just used `npm install`

Comment: We'll just from your post I see that the two links you posted are v3 and v4

Comment: I am sorry, My question was how to use `npm` inbuild .scss files in laravel for responsive , although externally its working.

Answer (score 0):

I am using classes mentioned here

```
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_responsive_utilities.htm
```

And its working with inbuilt bootstrap css node modules in laravel 5.3

Answer (score 0):

The import from laravel is Bootstrap v3.

The classes you are referring to are from Bootstrap v4. If you want to use Bootstrap v3 remove the `@import` that laravel provides.

If you do this you have to import Bootstrap v4 yourself, which can be done by downloading the files and including it in your `<head></head>` , using the gulpfile , using a CDN ,..

I would recommend still using Bootstrap v3 . In that case just leave everything alone and remove those CDN links that you have now. And use the classes provided in the Bootstrap v3 documentation:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Yes I moved to bootstrap version 3 classes